# How can i solve these RuntimeWarning errors?

Tags: python

```
import threading
import asyncio
import discord
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

client = discord.Client()

def set_interval(func, sec):
    async def func_wrapper():
        set_interval(func, 1)
        await func()
    t = threading.Timer(sec, func_wrapper)
    t.start()
    return t

async def takip():
    url = ""

    R = requests.get(url)
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(R.text, "html5lib")

    Title = Soup.find("h1", {"class": "pr-new-br"}).getText()
    List = Soup.find("div", {"class": "pr-bx-nm with-org-prc"})

    fiyat = List.find("span", {"class": "prc-dsc"}).getText()

    degisenfiyat = float(fiyat.replace(",", ".").replace(" TL", ""))

    if (degisenfiyat <= 200):
        channel = client.get_channel(973939538357522474)
        await channel.send("Fiyat düştü.")

    print(Title)
    print(fiyat)
    print(degisenfiyat)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
    set_interval(takip, 1)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run("")
```

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'set_interval.<locals>.func_wrapper' was never awaited
  self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

This is a function works with discord.py to solve a scraping problem. But when trying to use set_interval function gives this error. How to solve it any idea?

Comment: As the error message says, `func_wrapper` was never awaited - there was no call like `await func_wrapper()`

Comment: Remove the `async` Keyword or parse an Lambda function to the thread with the `await` keyword

Comment: @DominikLovetinsky Should i remove all async keywords

Comment: @DominikLovetinsky i did and app gave that `SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function`

Comment: Do you need to await the call to `func`?

Comment: Yes and i need to solve this error